# Sparse matrix representation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, sparse-matrix

I have 2 questions regarding sparse matrix representation.

[image: matrix example]

[image: Example i followed]

Based on the matrix example that i have provided above, I need to propose a solution to represent a sparse matrix.

I thought of representing the sparse matrix using **linked list**.

**Can you guys suggest to me a proper algorithm for both of my questions? Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to represent sparse objects and while all can be implemented in any language, some languages are better at implementing a certain representation than others. Some representations make more efficient storage but are slow on matrix operations while others provide for faster matrix operations but storage requirements are larger.

For example:

1. Hash of values where key is row/column of non-zero element eg `Matrix.hash[(i,j)]`, `Matrix.hash[(i,j)] = n`
2. Linked list of non-zero rows, each entry is a linked list of non-zero columns. eg `Matrix.rows.get(i).get(j)`, `Matrix.rows.set(i, (j, n))`
3. Condensed row space representation, CSR (see reference below)

References and examples:

1. [Sparse Matrix and its representations | Set 1 (Using Arrays and Linked Lists)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representation/)
2. [Sparse Matrix and its representations | Set 2 (Using List of Lists and Dictionary of keys)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representations-using-list-lists-dictionary-keys/)
3. [Sparse Matrix Representations | Set 3 ( CSR )](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representations-set-3-csr/)

To display the contents of a sparse matrix one simply loops:

```
for all rows i=1 to n:
    for all columns j=1 to m:
        if Matrix.has(i,j): display Matrix.get(i,j)
        else: display 0
    display newLine
```

**Note**, depending on chosen representation, the printing loop may be optimised a bit, of course it has to loop through all rows and columns, but, for example, `.has` and `.get` operations may be merged into one optimised `.get` and so on..

**UPDATED question:**

For the **list of lists** representation, the pseudo-code to insert a new non-zero value `n` at row `i` column `j` would be something like the following:

```
function insert(matrix, n/*value*/, i/*row*/, j/*column*/)
{
    row = matrix.rows, prevrow = null;
    while(null!=row && row.index<i) { prevrow=row; row=row.next; }
    if ( !row )
    {
       if ( prevrow )
       {
           // rows with indexes less than i
           prevrow.next = {
               index:i,
               columns:{
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:null
               }, 
               next:null
            };
       }
       else
       {
           // empty matrix
           matrix.rows = {
               index:i,
               columns: {
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:null
               }, 
               next:null
            };
       }
    }
    else if ( row.index == i )
    {
        // insert column to existing row i
        col = row.columns; prevcol = null;
        while(null!=col && col.index<j){ prevcol=col; col=col.next; }
        if ( !col )
        {
           if ( prevcol )
           {
               // row with column indexes less than j
               prevcol.next = {
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:null
              };
           }
           else
           {
            // empty row
               row.columns = {
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:null
               };
           }
        }
        else if ( col.index == j )
        {
            // change value to existing column j
            col.value = n;
        }
        else
        {
            // insert new column at right place
            if ( prevcol )
            {
               prevcol.next = { 
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:col
               };
            }
            else
            {
                row.columns = {
                  index:j,
                  value:n,
                  next:col
                };
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // insert new row/column at right place
        if ( prevrow )
        {
            prevrow.next = { 
              index:i,
              columns:{
                 index:j,
                 value:n,
                 next:null
              },
              next: row
           };
        }
        else
        {
            matrix.rows = {
                index:i,
                columns:{
                   index:j,
                   value:n,
                   next:null
                },
                next:row
            };
         }
    }
}
```

For **list of lists** representation the printing looop may be optimised a bit like the following (pseudo-code):

```
function print(matrix, n/*rows*/, m/*columns*/)
{
    row = matrix.rows;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if ( !row || (row.index > i) )
        {
            for(j=0; j<m; j++) print('0 ');
        }
        else if ( row.index == i )
        {
            col = row.columns
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                if ( !col || (col.index > j) )
                {
                    print('0 ');
                }
                else if ( col.index == j )
                {
                    print(string(col.value)+' ');
                    col = col.next;
                }
            }
            row = row.next;
        }

        print("\n"); // print new line
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my main question is not how to represent the sparse matrix. My main question is hw i suppose to insert of new element into the matrix using linked list? Hope u get what i mean

Comment: @SharanaDharshikgan, this is included in the answer and the references related to linked-list representation. In any case it is good to know about possible representations and choose one that is best. If you need further clarifications let me know

Comment: @SharanaDharshikgan there are 2 distinct representations using linked lists, linked list of row/column index and list of lists. Both use linked lists. Maybe one can think of other representations using linked lists as well. The references discuss both these approaches and more. Once you get the idea of the representation and sample code you get the answers to your questions. If you have a more specific question let me know

Comment: thanks for the info man. But i already managed to represent the sparse matrix based on the matrix example above. I have just attached the image of the example in the question. But im just not sure how to do the algorithm for insert and display

Comment: @SharanaDharshikgan, updated answer. Note that this is only the algorithm idea in pseudo-code, you should implement details specific to the language you indent to use for the implementation.

Comment: thanks man. Just need one last help from you. Can u share with me the algorithm for insert and display for singly linked list based on the linked list i have added in the question above.

Comment: @SharanaDharshikgan, you should try to find it yourself based on all the examples and explanations already given. Once you have tried sth yourself and you have a problem ask another specific question. it is not difficult, why dont you try yourself.

Comment: i did try to work on the singly linked list for the past 12 hours bro. Still couldn't get the proper solution. Sorry to bother you bro, but im still new to data structures just started 5 days ago. Really hope that you can help me out here. Thanks in advance